# Perl- Using Local modules

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan

I'm using a hosted Linux machine so I don't have permissions to write into the ***/usr/lib*** directory.

I need `Spreadsheet::Read` and few other modules to be installed. I have all these required libraries in my local home directory.

In the perl code, I am using-

```
#include local module
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/perl5/lib/perl5";
use lib "$Bin/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi";
use Getopt::Long;
use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Template;
use lib "$Bin";
use Register;
```

So I have Spreadsheet and other libraries in the path ***../perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi***. But still when I run, I get this error:

> Uncaught exception from user code:
>           Parser for XLSX is not installed at ./main.pl line 42  at /home/nxf36037/ipxact-register-generator-master/code/perl5/lib/perl5/Spreadsheet/Read.pm
>   line 416
>           Spreadsheet::Read::ReadData('reg1000.xlsx') called at ./main.pl line 42

This is my line 42:

```
my $book  = ReadData($input);
```

I am unwilling to use `local::lib`, Could you please help with this issue?

Comment: I would recommend using [`perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl/) and then `cpanm` to install the missing modules instead of using this setup with `lib` and `FindBin`. Then `cpanm` would automatically find and install missing dependencies

Comment: [`Spreadsheet::Read`](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Spreadsheet-Read/Read.pm) needs additional modules to read various file formats, namely, it needs `Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX` to read `.xlsx` files.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I tried installing perlbrew , After installation it asks me to edit .bash_profile file. I don't have permission to edit it.

Comment: @MohitGandhi Hi. I think you can put the edits in `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile`. Feel free to contact me by email if you have further questions.